# Use elliptic curves certificate only if client support them

Tags: tls, ecc

Is it possible to send an EC certificate to a client if it supports it or send a regular certificate if it doesn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ECDSA certificates can only be used together with the *_ECDSA_* ciphers, i.e. ciphers like TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P256. The client sends the list of supported ciphers within the  ClientHello initiating the TLS handshake, so it is in theory possible for a server to decide based on these ciphers which certificate to send.

In practice support for this feature varies, but there is [support in Apache 2.4](https://blog.joelj.org/dual-rsaecdsa-certificates-in-apache-2-4/) and [support was added to nginx in version 1.11.0](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/814). In both cases you need at OpenSSL with at least version 1.0.2.

Comment: "Support for parallel ECDSA / RSA certificates " - exactly what I've searched for. For nginx, it was ready just 4 weeks ago.

Comment: How does selection work for Apache? Any documentation?

Comment: @SmitJohnth: I don't find any documentation but I don't know what else apart from the offered client ciphers they could reliably use to find out what the client supports.